# Video drivers stopped working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After rebooting video drivers stopped working. Video card is detected by linux. Things I tried:

1. Purging everything from nvidia and reinstalling proprietary drivers
2. Trying xorg drivers
3. Trying different versions of nvidia drivers
4. Booting from different version of linux kernel
5. Purging and reinstalling cuda

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04, 5.8.0-45-generic

Nothing worked and I'm stuck with 1024x768 resolution

I have duo OS setup and in Windows its all good